# What is the most recommended way to store time in PostgreSQL using Java?

Tags: java, postgresql, date, jdbc

I'm storing two dates in the PostgreSQL database. First, is the data of visit of a webpage, and the second date is the date of last modification of the webpage(this is get as a long).

I have some doubts what is the best strategy to store these values.

I only need day/month/year and hour:seconds and this will only for statistical proposes.

So, some doubts:

- is best store as long and convert on recover of information or store in the data format above?
- is best set the date of visit on the software or in the insertion in the database?
- in Java, how are the best classes to handle dates?

Comment: The word "date" is overloaded, but its most usual meaning is year-month-day, without time. Perhaps you'd better say "datetime" or "timestamp" in the post title and body.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Any strategy for storing date-and-time data in PostgreSQL should, IMO, rely on these two points:

- Your solution should *never* depend on the server or client timezone setting.
- Currently, PostgreSQL (as most databases) doesn't have a datatype to store a *full* date-and-time with timezone. So, you need to decide between an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) or a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) datatype.

My recipe follows.

---

If you want to record the physical **instant** at when a particular event  ocurred, (a true "**timestamp**" , typically some creation/modification/deletion event),  then use:

- Java: [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) (Java 8 , or Jodatime).
- JDBC: `java.sql.Timestamp`
- PostgreSQL: [`TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html) (`TIMESTAMPTZ`)

(Don't let PostgreSQL peculiar datatypes `WITH TIMEZONE`/`WITHOUT TIMEZONE` confuse you: none of them actually stores a timezone)

Some boilerplate code: the following assumes that `ps` is a `PreparedStatement`, `rs` a `ResultSet` and `tzUTC` is a static `Calendar` object corresponding to `UTC` timezone.

```
public static final Calendar tzUTC = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Write `Instant` to database `TIMESTAMPTZ`:

```
Instant instant = ...;
Timestamp ts = instant != null ? Timestamp.from(instant) : null;
ps.setTimestamp(col, ts, tzUTC);   // column is TIMESTAMPTZ!
```

Read `Instant` from database `TIMESTAMPTZ`:

```
Timestamp ts = rs.getTimestamp(col,tzUTC); // column is TIMESTAMPTZ
Instant inst = ts !=null ? ts.toInstant() : null;
```

This works safely if your PG type is `TIMESTAMPTZ` (In that case, the `calendarUTC` has no effect in that code ; but it's always advisable to not depend on defaults timezones).
"Safely" means that the result will **not depend on server or database timezone**, or timezones information: the operation is fully reversible, and whatever happens to timezones settings, you'll always get the same "instant of time" you originally had on the Java side.

---

If, instead of a timestamp (an instant on the physical timeline), you are dealing with a **"civil" local date-time** (that is, the set of fields `{year-month-day hour:min:sec(:msecs)}`), you'd use:

- Java: [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) (Java 8 , or Jodatime).
- JDBC: `java.sql.Timestamp`
- PostgreSQL: [`TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIMEZONE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html) (`TIMESTAMP`)

Read `LocalDateTime` from database `TIMESTAMP`:

```
Timestamp ts = rs.getTimestamp(col, tzUTC); //
LocalDateTime localDt = null;
if( ts != null ) 
    localDt =  LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(ts.getTime()), ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

Write `LocalDateTime` to database `TIMESTAMP`:

```
  Timestamp ts = null;
  if( localDt != null)    
      ts = new Timestamp(localDt.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli()), tzUTC);
  ps.setTimestamp(colNum,ts, tzUTC);
```

Again, this strategy is safe and you can sleep peacefully: if you stored `2011-10-30 23:59:30` , you'll retrieve those precise fields (hour=23, minute=59... etc) always, no matter what - even if tomorrow the timezone of your Postgresql server (or client) changes, or your JVM or your OS timezone, or if your country modifies its DST rules, etc.

---

Added:  If you want (it seems a natural requirement) to store the full datetime specification (a [`ZonedDatetime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html): the timestamp together with the timezone, which implicitly also includes the full civil datetime info - plus the timezone)... then I have bad news for you: PostgreSQL hasn't a datatype for this (neither other databases, to my knowledge). You must devise your own storage, perhaps in a pair of fields: could be the two above types (highly redundant, though efficient for retrieval and calculation), or one of them plus the time offset (you lose the timezone info, some calculations become difficult, and some impossible), or one of them plus the timezone (as string; some calculations can be extremely costly).

Comment: Good answer but now outdated as of Java 8 and later, where we now have the built-in [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework (inspired by Joda-Time).

Comment: @BasilBourque, I have never used JodaTime, and I just started using Java 8. To me this answer translates almost 1-to-1 with Java 8 APIs.

Comment: Can't be sure for yoda, but you should NOT save the Timestamp with TZ when using Java 8 Instant.

Instant is UTC. So will be the timestamp.

It does not need a TZ, and saving it can lead to mistakes. Cost me several hours, using Jooq, because it wrote the TIMESTAMPTZ correctly, but did not used the timezone as expected when reading values.

Comment: In reference to the storage of the timezone literal my question answered by Craig Ringer maybe of help as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12331962/should-i-store-the-timezone-separately-from-the-timestamp-for-postgres-and-jdbc/12338749 . It is a good idea to store the timezone that the client original chose at the instant time particularly for calendaring apps.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just save the seconds/milliseconds since epoch GMT in DB, in `bigint`? Which is unambiguous: one value of long will represent only one moment in every place in the world, and can be converted to different form of representation in every timezone. Considering this, `long` would be the best. If DST rules changes, a "civil" local date-time would change; I would not say it's "safe": now Europe may change its rule of DST and some datetime which are impossible to occur will be possible to appear.

Comment: @mlorber I realize your comment is very old, but it is not correct, you definitely should be using timestamp with tz in almost every case. I recommend reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627289/what-is-the-most-recommended-way-to-store-time-in-postgresql-using-java. Catch: you do need to set your JVM to UTC so postgres interprets the incoming string correctly.

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek you're right, not saving it is only ok with JVM set to UTC on your different environments

Comment: With JDBC 4.2, it is possible to use PreparedStatement.setObject and ResultSet.getObject with java.time types instead of get/setTime and get/setTimestamp.

LocalDateTime ldt = ResultSet#getObject(<column>, LocalDateTime.class);

Answer (score 5):

## java.time

It's not pretty but this is what worked for me with a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) instance using the new [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework in Java 8 and later ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html)):

```
ZonedDateTime receivedTimestamp = some_ts_value;
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(receivedTimestamp.toInstant().toEpochMilli());
ps.setTimestamp(
   1, 
   ts, 
   Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(receivedTimestamp.getZone()))
);
```

Comment: (a) This answer does not exactly fit the intent of the question. (b) There is a more direct approach with this code. The old classes such as `java.sql.Timestamp` were retrofitted in Java 8 and later with convenience methods for converting to/from the new java.time types. So:  `java.sql.Timestamp ts = java.sql.Timestamp.fromInstant( myZonedDateTime.toInstant() );`

Answer (score -3):

I had used java.util.Date in our code to store Date in arguments of my query. I was using Spring JPA and using @Query annotations. The implementation worked.