# Should I store the timezone separately from the timestamp for Postgres and JDBC?

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, jdbc

It seems (and maybe I'm wrong) that if you want to preserve the timezone of when something happened with JDBC and Postgres you need to store the timezone separately from the timestamp.

That is I would prefer to give my ORM/JDBC/JPA a Java `Calendar` (or Joda `DataTime`) with say timezone `America/New_York` to a Postgres `timestampz` field. AND I would expect on retrieval regardless of the Servers timezone (or defaulting to UTC) to give me back a `Calendar` with timezone `America/New_York`. But just looking at most JDBC code (and things that depend on it that doesn't happen).

**Is this correct?**

This seems ridiculous that I would need to store the tz in another field when postgres supports it.

Thus it seems like the only two options are:

1. Select the `timestampz` Postgres column as a `java.util.String` and parse it.
2. Store the timezone as a separate field.

Option number one and two one would require some sort of conversion interceptors for my SQL mapping / ORM libraries.

- What is the best solution for JDBC ?
- What is the best solution for JPA (if different than JDBC)?

Comment: When you store a `timestamptz` it's converted to UTC for storage in the DB. When retrieved, it's converted to the client's *current* timezone, not the timezone it was originally in. It's a point in time, basically.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you store a `timestamp with time zone` (`timestamptz`) it's converted to UTC for storage in the DB. When retrieved, it's converted to the client's current timezone, not the timezone it was originally in. It's a point in time, basically.

There is also `timestamp without time zone` (`timestamp`). This is not subject to conversion, but does *not* carry a timestamp with it. If you store a `timestamp` with your client time zone set to UTC, then retrieve it when the client time zone is '+08:00', you get the same value. That's half what you want, in that it preserves the raw time value.

The names and behaviours are awful and confusing, but set by the SQL standard.

You must store the time zone separately if you wish to record a point in time at a particular time zone. I'd recommend storing it as an `INTERVAL` with a `CHECK` constraint limiting it to be `colname BETWEEN INTERVAL '-12' HOUR + INTERVAL '1' SECOND AND INTERVAL '12' HOUR`. That definition rejects -12:00 and accepts +12:00; I'm not totally sure that's right, so check.

You could either store the `timestamp` of local time at that time zone (what I'd probably do), or store the `timestamptz` of the UTC time when the event occurred plus an offset that lets you convert it to local time.

Either will work fine for JDBC. For JPA, it'll depend on how well your provider understands and maps interval types. Ideally you want a transient generated field in your entity that reconstructs the Calendar instance you want using the `timestamp` and `interval` stored in the database.

Comment: Its probably ideal that I store the literal time zone name instead of the tz offset (ie `America/New_York` instead of -4 or -5) so that I can recover DST properly.

Comment: @AdamGent in which case you might want to know about SELECT current_setting('TIMEZONE') to get the client timezone when storing. Validating the field is hard, though, as the timezone may be set by the client as an offset, a full timezone name, or as a potentially non-unique tz abbreviation like "EST" ("Eastern States Time", Australia? Or "Eastern Standard Time", USA? Pg accepts both, selecting between them based on the value of `timezone_abbreviations`). Better to get the value from Java in a known form.

Answer (score 0):

EclipseLink supports storing the timezone in Oracle, I think you could get it to be stored in Postgres as well if you customized your PostgreSQLPlatform.

Comment: I using crappy hibernate which I'm beginning to loathe. One of these days I'm just going to switch to pure JDBC.