# Transfer timezone in pg_dump

Tags: postgresql, timezone, pg-dump, pg-restore

I have a time zone in PostgreSQL created like this:

```
ALTER DATABASE mydatabase SET TimeZone = 'MST';
```

I would like to use the preset time zone in restored database as well. If I backup it via `pg_dump` and restore with `pg_restore` the `pg_settings/TimeZone` is set back to localtime.

How can I transfer timezone?

Comment: Your question is valid and this is not the answer but anyway: your application should never depend on the default PG server timezone.

Comment: @leonbloy If you transfer database let's say from India to France, how can you see India's local timestamp? E.g. item was added to database at 21:25 local (India) time and you want to see same time (21:25) in France as well. Instead you'll see something like 16:55 + India's timezone.

Comment: You need to take advantage of TIMESTAMP vs TIMESTAMPTZ data types. See eg my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627289/what-is-the-most-recommended-way-to-store-time-in-postgresql-using-java/6627999#6627999

Answer (score 2):

example:

```
t=# create database z;
CREATE DATABASE
t=# alter database z set timezone to 'UTC+2';
ALTER DATABASE
t=# select now();
             now
------------------------------
 2018-01-17 08:41:10.12834+00
(1 row)
t=# \c z
You are now connected to database "z" as user "postgres".
z=# select now();
              now
-------------------------------
 2018-01-17 06:41:15.588483-02
(1 row)
```

as you can see after connecting to database `z` client "default" `TimeZone` changed. But you should not think, that dates changed in the database - no. [all timezone aware timestamps are kept in UTC](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html).

> For timestamp with time zone, the internally stored value is always in
>   UTC

Now back to your question. Indeed:

```
z-# \! pg_dump -d z  | grep "TimeZone"
```

if you backup database *z*, no its settings exported. So you need to use `pg_dumpall`:

```
z-# \! pg_dumpall | grep "TimeZone"
ALTER DATABASE z SET "TimeZone" TO 'UTC+2';
```

Comment: pg_dumpall - that's it, thanks! It'd be better if it could dump a single database and not the whole cluster only, but still...

Comment: you can use `-s` to dump definitions only - will save much time I assume